# Как отправлять вебхуками дискорда файлы?

Tags: python, discord

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вообщем, я сделал скрипт который копирует сообщения из другого сервера дискорда, и отправляет на какой-то вебхук. Но, самое главная проблема в том что я не имею знаний сделать чтобы код мог отправлять скопированное изображение на вебхук. вот код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dhooks import Webhook
import requests

idneeded = int("channelid")
isself = ("True")
token = ("usertoken")
webhooklink = ("webhook")
hook = Webhook(webhooklink.replace("app", ""))

if isself == "True":
    selfbot = True
    botrunner = False

elif isself == "False":
    selfbot = False
    botrunner = True



bot = commands.Bot( command_prefix = '!', self_bot=selfbot )

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if before.channel.id == idneeded:
       hook.send(f'**{before.author}** отредактировал сообщение.\n**Предыдущий вид**\n{before.content}\n**Настоящее время**\n{after.content}')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == idneeded:
       hook.send(f'**{message.author}:**\n{message.content}')


    else:
        pass


bot.run(token, bot = botrunner)
```

вот скрины его работы:[image: dd]

вот ссылка на библиотеку dhooks:
https://github.com/kyb3r/dhooks